# Passar variável do PHP para o JS através de JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estou tentando exibir o resultado de um *select* realizado pelo PHP em um arquivo externo, no um formulário HTML. Estou usando JSON para receber as variáveis, porém nada é exibido. 
Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir o erro ou me explicar uma forma melhor de exibir os dados, já pesquisei e não encontrei nada!

Página do formulário:

```
function Select_Produto(valor){
        IDProduto = valor;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        var url = "PHP/Produto_SelectVar.php?valor="+valor;
        req.open("Get", url, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            var resposta = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
               document.getElementById('Dados_cProd').value = resposta.Dados_cProd;
               document.getElementById('Dados_xProd').value = resposta.Dados_xProd;
               document.getElementById('Dados_NCM').value = resposta.Dados_NCM;
               document.getElementById('Dados_EXTIPI').value = resposta.Dados_EXTIPI;
               document.getElementById('Dados_CEST').value = resposta.Dados_CEST;
               document.getElementById('Dados_CFOP').value = resposta.Dados_CFOP;
               document.getElementById('Dados_uCom').value = resposta.Dados_uCom;
               document.getElementById('Dados_qCom').value = resposta.Dados_qCom;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vUnCom').value = resposta.Dados_vUnCom;
               document.getElementById('Dados_uTrib').value = resposta.Dados_uTrib;
               document.getElementById('Dados_qTrib').value = resposta.Dados_qTrib;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vUnTrib').value = resposta.Dados_vUnTrib;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vSeg').value = resposta.Dados_vSeg;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vDesc').value = resposta.Dados_vDesc;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vFrete').value = resposta.Dados_vFrete;
               document.getElementById('Dados_cEAN').value = resposta.Dados_cEAN;
               document.getElementById('Dados_cEANTrib').value = resposta.Dados_cEANTrib;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vOutro').value = resposta.Dados_vOutro;
               document.getElementById('Dados_vProd').value = resposta.Dados_vProd;
               document.getElementById('Dados_xPed').value = resposta.Dados_xPed;
               document.getElementById('Dados_nItemPed').value = resposta.Dados_nItemPed;
               document.getElementById('Dados_nFCI').value = resposta.Dados_nFCI;
               document.getElementById('Dados_NVE').value = resposta.Dados_NVE;
            }
        }
        req.send(null);
    }



insira o código aqui
```

Pagina de consulta

```
echo  $array = array('Dados_cProd'=>$Dados_cProd,
                     'Dados_xProd'=>$Dados_xProd,
                     'Dados_NCM'=>$Dados_NCM,
                     'Dados_EXTIPI'=>$Dados_EXTIPI,
                     'Dados_CEST'=>$Dados_CEST,
                     'Dados_CFOP'=>$Dados_CFOP,
                     'Dados_uCom'=>$Dados_uCom,
                     'Dados_qCom'=>$Dados_qCom,
                     'Dados_vUnCom'=>$Dados_vUnCom,
                     'Dados_uTrib'=>$Dados_uTrib,
                     'Dados_qTrib'=>$Dados_qTrib,
                     'Dados_vUnTrib'=>$Dados_vUnTrib,
                     'Dados_vSeg'=>$Dados_vSeg,
                     'Dados_vDesc'=>$Dados_vDesc,
                     'Dados_vFrete'=>$Dados_vFrete,
                     'Dados_cEAN'=>$Dados_cEAN,
                     'Dados_cEANTrib'=>$Dados_cEANTrib,
                     'Dados_vOutro'=>$Dados_vOutro,
                     'Dados_vProd'=>$Dados_vProd,
                     'Dados_xPed'=>$Dados_xPed,
                     'Dados_nItemPed'=>$Dados_nItemPed,
                     'Dados_nFCI'=>$Dados_nFCI,
                     'Dados_NVE'=>$Dados_NVE);
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Modal do Formulário

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="MDProdutos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="MDProdutosLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="MDProdutosLabel">Produtos e serviços</h4>
                      </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="row">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Código</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_cProd" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Descrição</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_xProd" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>NCM</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_NCM" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>EX TIPI</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_EXTIPI" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>CEST</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_CEST" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <label>CFOP</label>
                                        <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="Dados_CFOP">
                                          <option></option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>UN. Comercial</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_uCom" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Qtd. Comercial</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_qCom" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Valor. Unid. Comercial</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vUnCom" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>UN. Trib.</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_uTrib" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Qtd. Trib.</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_qTrib" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Valor. Unid. Trib.</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vUnTrib" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Tot. Seguro</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vSeg" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Desconto</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vDesc" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Tot. Frete</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vFrete" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>EAN</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_cEAN" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>EAN Trib.</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_cEANTrib" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Outras Desp. Acessórias</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vOutro" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Valor Tot. Bruto</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_vProd" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label style="padding-top: 1.5rem;">
                                              <input type="checkbox" id="indTot"> Valor total bruto compõe o valor total dos produtos e serviços
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Pedido de compra</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_xPed" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Número do item do pedido de compra</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_nItemPed" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Número de controle da FCI</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Dados_nFCI" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">NVE</label>
                                            <input  class="form-control" id="Dados_NVE" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                          </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="Inserir_Produtos()">Salvar</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Por que ao invés de tentar exibir os dados das variáveis com PHP você não tenta exibir esses dados com jQuery mesmo?

Comment: Porque os dados são resultados de uma query do MySql.

Comment: Coloca o código HTML também.

Comment: Coloca um `console.log` na variável `resposta` e posta aqui os que aparece.

Comment: Faça o debug no navegador, no Chrome aperte f12 na aba superior selecione 'Network', e acione a requisição ajax, ai vai aparecer o arquivo php aonde foi enviada a requisição, lá vai ter os headers que foram mandados,  na aba response você pode ver mensagens de erro, e muito provavelmente aonde está o erro.

Comment: VM2354:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Select_Produto.req.onreadystatechange (Produtos_e_servicos.php?id=8:4223)
Select_Produto.req.onreadystatechange @ Produtos_e_servicos.php?id=8:4223

Comment: No console aparece que tem erro de sintaxe no array do json, os dados são carregados corretamente, porém não consigo identificar o erro. 

Array{"Dados_cProd":"12334556","Dados_xProd":"","Dados_NCM":"","Dados_EXTIPI":"","Dados_CEST":"","Dados_CFOP":"0","Dados_uCom":"","Dados_qCom":"0.0000","Dados_vUnCom":"0.0000000000","Dados_uTrib":"","Dados_qTrib":"0.0000","Dados_vUnTrib":"0.0000","Dados_vSeg":"0.00","Dados_vDesc":"0.00","Dados_vFrete":"0.00","Dados_cEAN":"","Dados_cEANTrib":"","Dados_vOutro":"0.00","Dados_vProd":"0.00","Dados_xPed":"","Dados_nItemPed":"","Dados_nFCI":"","Dados_NVE":""}

Comment: Atualizei com o modal do formulário que eu estou tentando preencher.

Comment: Amigo tem uns caracteres especiais dentro desse JSON. http://prnt.sc/dn4yy2

Comment: A codificação do seu php está UTF-8?

Comment: Está em UTF-8 sim.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pela força! Realmente era problema na codificação UTF-8, alterei o código php e funcionou.